# Local IP address changed and cannot access magento Backend/Frontend

Tags: magento

I had magento installed few days back. My IP address is not stable. I had different ip address when installed and now since the IP address is changed, i cannot login to magento. When i use my new ip address in the url, it redirects to my old ip address but the page is blank. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the base URL in your DB:

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' and value='ip';
update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url' and value='ip';
```

([ref](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html))

Comment: Just a note: the code listed above will affect all store views. It doesn't sound like Techsavy has more than one store view, but if he or she does then this could introduce problems. A more targeted fix would be to replace instances of the IP address listed above in core config data with the new IP address and or a host name

Comment: Replace the IP address with a host name and create an entry in the hosts file to resolve the assigned IP to the hostname (Linux => `/etc/hosts` or Windows => `X:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`) Then it stops mattering what the IP is, just change it in the hosts file and you don't have to hunt'n replace in the database.